# when reducer is first called

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When is Reducer is first called ?

1. Reducer starts copying intermediate key-value pairs from each mapper as soon as it has completed. The programmer can configure in the job what percentage of intermediate data should arrive before the reducer begins.
2. Reducer starts copying intermediate key-value pairs from each mapper as soon as it has completed.Reduce() method is called as soon as intermediate key-value pairs start to arrive.

Which statement holds true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both statements are false:

Reducers start copying intermediate key value pair from each mapper as soon as the mapper has completed - if 5% (by default, configure mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps) of mappers completed.

Reduce() method is called when ALL mappers completed and Reducer copied and sorted (merged) ALL data from Mappers.